# How do I structure(process) such a table for model training?

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

The dataset contains different items row-wise and the columns contain the samples recorded where half are of positive class and the other half are of negative class. Now, I want to create and train a model to classify unseen item sample as positive or negative.

*Question*: How do I handle(use) such a dataset?

And, any recommendation for model as the number of rows is more than 50k and the number of columns are 12 positive and 12 negative.

[image: dataset structure]

Now, from this data, a model is to created that can classify x(or y or z) as positive or negative based on the value provided. For example, if the value provided for x is 12, then the model evaluates x as positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as I understand your question, you have a variable as input, let's say x. This variable can hold some values (the positive examples) but not other (the negative examples). Now, given a new value for x, you want to know if such value is plausible for x.

You talked about training. I guess you are thinking at neural networks. In this case, simply create a dataset out of the first row of your table (x-row) as follows:

```
D = [
 [10, 1],
 [11, 1],
 [13, 1],
 [14, 1],
 [16, 0],
 [15, 0],
 [14, 0],
 [16, 0],
]
```

The first element is your value. The second element tells your network if is a plausible value (1) or not (0). Remember to shuffle your dataset to avoid the samples you feed your network with to be highly correlated (in theory, they should be iid).

Your network will have as input only 1 neuron an as output 1 neuron. Last layer will be a sigmoid activation function (because it is confined between 0 and 1). Use the Binary cross entropy loss.

---

Given the comment, here's the updated answer.

The dataset must be the following:

```
D = [
 [10, 0.67, 25, ..., 1],
 [16, 0.15, 20.5, ..., 0],
 [...]
]
```

The network is identical to the one described above, but now the input has dimensionality equal to the number of rows.

Comment: I had a thought like this, but this would mean that I will have to create a dataset for each row and my dataset contains more than 50k rows. And consider the samples as items that have properties x,y,z,etc. Also, my goal here is feature selection to know the influence of each row(property) on the positivity or negativity of a sample.